# Why the 3D Texture based Volume Rendering has no 3D effects

Tags: c#, opentk

I implemented an 3D Texture based Volume Rendering using [OpenTK](https://github.com/opentk/opentk). The code is based on this [project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/352270/Getting-started-with-Volume-Rendering). But the result showed no 3D effects, just flat 2D image.

The pipeline is simple enough: (1) Load 3D texture; (2) draw a series of quads(rectangles) and specify the corresponding texture coordinates.

The Vertices of each quads were generated using

```
private void generateVertices(int n)
    {
        vertices = new float[n * 3 * 4];
        int cur;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            cur = 3 * 4 * i;

            vertices[cur] = -.5f;
            vertices[cur + 1] = -.5f;
            vertices[cur + 2] = -0.5f + i / n;

            vertices[cur+3] = -.5f;
            vertices[cur + 4] = .5f;
            vertices[cur + 5] = -0.5f +  i / n;

            vertices[cur+6] = .5f;
            vertices[cur + 7] = .5f;
            vertices[cur + 8] = -0.5f +  i / n;

            vertices[cur+9] = .5f;
            vertices[cur + 10] = -.5f;
            vertices[cur + 11] = -0.5f + i / n;
        }
    }
```

To draw 256 quads, just call generateVertices(256) and opengl routine

> GLDrawElements(GL_QUADS,...)

The TexCoordinates were calculated using vertices position in vertex shader like this:

```
texCoord = aPosition+vec3(0.5f,0.5f,0.5f);
```

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: I voted to close the question because it lacks a _minimal, complete, and verifiable example_, and because it's not at all clear (to me) what OP's problem here is. How should anyone know what they should expect to see by looking at a function that generates some vertices? Also, the codeproject article is relying on the obsolete OpenGL pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

Integer *i* at range [0,n-1], *i/n* will be 0 forever.
So you indeed specify n overlaped quads.

The solution is simple, just explicitly cast i to float `（float）i/n`.

Comment: If `n == 0`, then it never enters the loop. If `n > 0`, then it does enter the loop, and `i` increases up to `n` (`n-1` is the last time the body gets exec'ed). From where do you assert that _"`i/n` will be 0 forever"_? This makes no sense.

Comment: Got it! I get an 3D volume rendered on the screen by making this changes: in the for-loop:
        {
            vertices[cur + 2] = -0.5f +1.0f* i / n;

            vertices[cur + 8] = -0.5f +  1.0f*i / n;

            vertices[cur + 11] = -0.5f +1.0f* i / n;
        }

Comment: @code_dredd integer 1 / integer 2 produce another integer 0. vertices[cur + 2] = -0.5f + i / n equals -0.5f forever. There are n rectangle with the same location added to VBO=> no 3d effets.

Comment: @ShannonChow I think adding that bit of info (i.e. the `int`-based truncation) to the answer and telling OP to cast `i` and/or `n` to a `float`, rather than "just multiply by `1.0f`" (which does the same, but less explicitly), would improve the answer. I'm not sure OP would necessarily understand _why_ that was a problem in the first place just from your post...